# Android canvas seek bar editing

Tags: android, imageview, seekbar, hue

In my app there is an image that the user imported using the gallery
then doen the imageview where the picture has been inserted
there is two seekbars

the first seekbar controls the picture brightness
and the other controls the picture hue

when I use them they are working, but the problem is they don't save
like ..

I imported the picture then made its brightness its working great
but when I set the picture hue the brightness that i made disappears
and the hue starts

isn't there

```
iv.save;
```

or anything like that?

note*

```
final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is.

```
final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
 iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp=iv.getDrawingCache();
```

Now you can save this Bitmap to your sdcard in jpg or png format.